# Is there an idiom that means something looks alive and real?

Tags: idiom-request

Is there an idiom that means something looks alive and real? I am pretty sure I have read or heard it before, but I can't remember it at all. If you can't think of an idiom that means that, can you think of an idiom that means something seems to be alive, or that means something looks real?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit vague as there is no context. You could have used a Thesaurus. Here is what I found at a quick look up
Cambridge Thesaurus: **lifelike** synonyms and related words
True, real, false, and unreal:
**all that glitters is not gold** idiom  **properly speaking** idiom **at heart** idiom **be a matter of record** idiom 
**be off the mar**k idiom  **have have a/the ring of tru**th idiom 
**hold true** idiom **hold water** idiom 
**in all but name** idiom 
**in name only** idiom 
**nothing could be further from the truth** idiom 
**nothing could have been further from my mind/thoughts** idiom 
**ring true** idiom 
**ring true/false** idiom
seeing things idiom 
**the fact remains** idiom 
**there's no escaping the fact** idiom 
**there's nothing in sth** idiom 
**there's something in sth** idiom

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but we generally discourage list-type answers and answers without explanations. Also, you can request more details from a users if you feel that the question is vague. It can definitely help everyone get on the same page. Please see the [Contributor's Guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4783/36187) for more tips.

Comment: It's cool, I need to learn my way around. But Thanks